# Combine flatMap/Scan to carry intermediate result

Tags: swift, functional-programming, rx-swift, reactive, moya

I often find my self chaining multiple http request with flatmap but sometimes i need to carry the result further than the next observable. How would I go about doing that?

Fx:

```
getAPIKey().flatMap( {key in 
    return getData1(key)
})
.flatMap({ (key, data) in 
   return getData2(key, data)
})
.map({ data in
   data.transform()
})
.subscribe(onNext: { transformed in
//Do something with data
})
```

This is not and actual example so don't get caught up on semantics.

Answer (score 2):

So i also posted this question on Slack for RxSwift.

This is the response I got from Zsolt Váradi (vzsg)

```
getFoo().flatMap { foo in
    getBars(ofFoo: foo.id).map { bars in (foo, bars) }
}
```

Hope this can help someone else